# How do you print a string to the printer in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I need to print a string from a textbox. The string should print through the default printer weather it is a parallel printer or a usb printer. Can this be done.

BTW..I am using .net Forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can use the `PrintDocument` class to print arbitrary content.

The [MSDN page on PrintDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx) contains a nice example which prints the contents of a file to the default printer. Adapting this to print the content of a text box instead should be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the [PrintDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx) class on MSDN and the [System.Drawing.Printing namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.aspx) in general.

From MSDN:

> The System.Drawing.Printing  namespace
>   provides print-related services for
>   Windows Forms applications.
>
> Typically, when you print from a
>   Windows Forms application, you create
>   a new instance of the PrintDocument
>   class, set properties, such as
>   DefaultPageSettings and
>   PrinterSettings, that describe how to
>   print, and call the Print method to
>   actually print the document. Calling
>   the PrintDocument.Print method raises
>   the PrintDocument.PrintPage event,
>   which should be handled to perform the
>   document layout for printing.
>
> Use the Graphics property of the
>   PrintPageEventArgs object obtained
>   from the PrintDocument.PrintPage event
>   to specify the output to print. If you
>   are printing a text file, use
>   StreamReader to read one line at a
>   time from the stream and call the
>   DrawString method to draw the line in
>   the graphics object. For more
>   information about this process, see
>   the Graphics and StreamReader classes.
>   You can view an example of printing a
>   text document in the PrintDocument
>   class overview topic.